# SelectedIndexChanged Not Firing in WinForms for Controls Generated at Runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, events, data-binding

My forehead is bruised from banging my head against my desk on this one.

I have a Form that generates a bunch of custom UserControls (FieldMapper objects) based on parameters passed to it.  The FieldMapper UserControl is essentially just a few labels, a BindingSource, and a ComboBox (bound to the BindingSource) organized on a TableLayoutPanel.  The ComboBox on this UserControl is set to DropDownList and is bound to the BindingSource, which gets populated with a IList passed as an argument at construction time.

The FieldMapper has an event called MappingChanged, which gets fired whenever the underlying SelectedIndexChanged event is fired and some logic determines the arguments for the MappingChangedEventArgs that are fired with the event.  This is used to remove/add items from other comboboxes so nothing can be selected twice in the series of FieldMapping controls

The problem is that **ONLY ONE** control fires the underlying SelectedIndexChanged event.  This control is whatever control I FIRST change it's ComboBox's selected value/index.  It doesn't matter which one I select, but only that control will fire subsequent events, although other control's combobox's were changed.

Here is the constructor for the FieldMapper *(removed parameters not concerning to the issue)*

```
public FieldMapper(IList<string> fields)
{
        InitializeComponent();

        fields = fields.OrderBy(s => s).ToList();
        string[] copyBuffer = new string[fields.Count + 1];
        fields.CopyTo(copyBuffer, 1);
        copyBuffer[0] = "NONE";
        AvailableMappings = new BindingList<string>(copyBuffer.ToList());
        AvailableMappings.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;

        bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        mapSelector.DataSource = bindingSource;
        bindingSource.DataSource = AvailableMappings;

        mapSelector.SelectedItem = "NONE";
        mapSelector.SelectedIndexChanged += mapSelector_SelectedIndexChanged;
}
```

The parent Form of these FieldMapper controls generates them as such:

```
private void BuildMappingTable(IEnumerable<string> fieldNames)
{
    int row = 0;
    foreach (var field in fbProject.Fields)
    {
        FieldMapper mapper = new FieldMapper(field.Key, field.Value.FieldName, fieldNames.ToList());
        mapper.EnableMappingField = false;
        mapper.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left;
        mapper.MappingChanged += MappingChanged;
        mappingTable.Controls.Add(mapper, 0, row);
        row++;
    }   
    if (!built && !original)
        SetInitialValues()

    built = true;
}
```

When I check the breakpoints when debugging this issue the event handlers are always populated for both the FieldMapper and the FieldMapper's comobobox's SelectedIndexChanged event, so I'm not sure why they aren't firing.

EDIT: As requested here is the mapSelector_SelectedIndexChanged method

```
private void mapSelector_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentValue == null || currentValue.Equals("NONE"))
        {
            currentValue = (string)mapSelector.SelectedItem;
            OnMappingChanged(new MappingSelectedEventArgs(MappingSelectedEventArgs.MappingSelectedAction.SET, currentValue));
        }
        else if (mapSelector.SelectedItem.Equals("NONE"))
        {
            OnMappingChanged(new MappingSelectedEventArgs(MappingSelectedEventArgs.MappingSelectedAction.REMOVED, currentValue));
            currentValue = "NONE";
        }
        else if (!mapSelector.SelectedItem.Equals(currentValue))
        {
            OnMappingChanged(new MappingSelectedEventArgs(MappingSelectedEventArgs.MappingSelectedAction.CHANGED, currentValue,
                (string)mapSelector.SelectedItem));
            currentValue = (string)mapSelector.SelectedItem;
        }
    }

    protected void OnMappingChanged(MappingSelectedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (MappingChanged != null)
            MappingChanged(this, args);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the body for mapSelector_SelectedIndexChanged please?

Comment: Your code looks OK to me.

Comment: @Kroonwijk updating it now

Answer (score -2):

Replace:

```
private void mapSelector_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

by:

```
private void bindingSource_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```